# Coroutines must be cancellation cooperative

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Looking at the official docs, it seems like a coroutine can only be cancelled if it cooperates with cancellation meaning it checks if it's active before executing its code. [LINK](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative)

If that's the case, how does scope.cancel() cancels all coroutines cancel/stop running inside that scope?

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    var nextPrintTime = startTime
    var i = 0
    while (i < 5) { // computation loop, just wastes CPU
        // print a message twice a second
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
            println("job: I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
            nextPrintTime += 500L
        }
    }
}
delay(1300L) // delay a bit
println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
job.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
println("main: Now I can quit.")
```

Comment: Unclear what your actually asking. Are you asking what goes on under the hood to achieve cancellation, or how to successfully make something cooperative with cancellation, or something else? What does your sample code have to do with your question? The code above does not cooperate with cancellation, so it will run to completion regardless of whether it’s cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually cancel the job. In the `job.cancelAndJoin()` the code waits until `while (i < 5)` is done and then the job exists.

If read the linked article to the end, you'll find the example of a cooperative job, which uses `while (isActive)`. `isActive` returns `false` when the job gets cancelled. When this happens, the while-loop will just quit normally.